# Using native HistoryAPI and History.js together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js

I am a little bit confused newbie of History API. Please help me in understanding this. I wrote this code using Native HistoryAPI:

```
function addClicker(link) {
    link.removeEventListener('click', null);
    link.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (swapData(link.href)) {
            if (prevlink != link.href) {
                history.pushState(null, null, link.href);
                prevlink = link.href;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }, true);
}

function setupHistoryClicks() {
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('hrlinks');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
        addClicker(links[i]);
}

function initHist() {
    if (!supports_history_api()) { return; }
    setupHistoryClicks();
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.addEventListener("popstate", function (e) {
            swapData(location.href); //a function that changes content according to URL
        }, false);
    }, 1);
    swapData(location.href);
}
```

This code overrides the click event of links with `hrlinks` as class and enable them to use history API.

But from past 2 days I am researching on History API and came to know that it's not very much reliable. And the other alternative is to use History.js.

What I want to know is that how can I use History.js when History API is not available? And do I need to change my code for that? Or I have to simply import History.js when native History API is not supported?

Comment: what is your swapdata function doing?

Comment: @Sunand I already wrote it in comments in code and it's just a function that changes page content according to URL

Comment: anyways, history.js works by appending a hash value in the url for mozilla and chrome. and adds a hidden iframe for ie. so when you use browser back it will take the change (from hash or iframe with respect to browser) and call ur function back with corresponding argument

Comment: Yeah I know that but how can I use it with native history api? I mean I want to use it for those browsers that doesn't support native history api and I also want to know how much code do I need to change?

Comment: i think not much changes are required instead to use "History" instead of history for current code